# Correct response to a wctp-MessageReply operation

Tags: wireless

I am sending [WCTP](http://www.wctp.org/) `wctp-SendMsgMulti` operations to my carrier (Verizon), and when people send SMSs in response I am receiving the notifications just fine.

#### Example Notification

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<wctp-Operation wctpVersion="wctp-dtd-v1r2">
  <wctp-MessageReply>
      <wctp-ResponseHeader responseTimestamp="2013-10-17T23:34:22.000Z" responseToMessageID="someLongId">
          <wctp-Originator senderID="7075551212"/>
          <wctp-MessageControl messageID="someLongId"/>
          <wctp-Recipient recipientID="myVzwLogin"/>
      </wctp-ResponseHeader>
      <wctp-Payload>
          <wctp-Alphanumeric>Yes</wctp-Alphanumeric>
      </wctp-Payload>
  </wctp-MessageReply>
</wctp-Operation>
```

Right now, I'm returning an empty HTTP 200 response to the notification.

If I poll the WCTP service after receiving the notification, I see the same `wctp-MessageReply` is still pending.  The carrier seems to think that it hasn't been delivered to me yet.

Since the notification arrives without a `sequenceNo`, I can't remove it using a `wctp-PollForMessages` operation.

I would love to be able to be able to respond to the notification in a way that tells the carrier not to keep the message queued, but the spec says nothing about what the proper response is to a `wctp-MessageReply` operation.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, in section 3.8 of the spec titled **Call Flow Between Network Elements**.  You're supposed to send a `wctp-Confirmation`.

Success:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<wctp-Operation wctpVersion="wctp-dtd-v1r2">
  <wctp-Confirmation>
    <wctp-Success successCode="200" successText="Reply received">Reply received</wctp-Success>
  </wctp-Confirmation>
</wctp-Operation>
```

Failure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<wctp-Operation wctpVersion="wctp-dtd-v1r2">
  <wctp-Confirmation>
    <wctp-Failure errorCode="300" errorText="Opertion not understood.">Operation not understood.</wctp-Failure>
  </wctp-Confirmation>
</wctp-Operation>
```

Comment: I've tested this, and it actually works.  Now, if only I could convince my carrier not to send queue notifications.  Apparently, Verizon's implementation is pretty spotty.